# how to display f.select with check boxes instead of a drop-down list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code and I want to make it display with checkboxes instead of the dropdown menu. Can that be achieved? .

```
<%= f.select :job_type_cont,[['Full Time','Full Time'],['Part Time','Part Time'],['Permanent','Permanent']],{:include_blank => 'All....'},class:"form-control",id:"bed_room" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For that is neccesary a checkbox input

First you need in you controller receive you parameter like an array:

```
params.require(:model).permit(:others, job_type_cont: [])
```

And later, you should do an each, like

```
<% job_type_conts = ['Full Time', 'Part Time', 'Permanent']%>
<% job_type_conts.each do |type| %>
  # Edit: Check id and for of label and checkbox input
  <%= f.check_box( :job_type_cont, { multiple: true, id: "#{type.gsub(" ","-")}"}, type ) %>
  <%= f.label :job_type_cont, type, for: "#{type.gsub(" ","-")}" %>
<% end %>
```

You can watch a good simple guide 
[Rails multiple checkboxes](https://medium.com/programming-problem-solving-logbook/rails-multiple-checkboxes-e9c4c7fda356) of Sophie Déziel.

Comment: i have this Error **syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' tiple: true },type,false label type);@output_buffer.safe_app ^** . I implemented the exact code above

Comment: Please check the last update where I put the "for" and "id"

Comment: Thanks, Using your above code, the labels display correctly, but when I select a checkbox, I get no result. In the console, I get this `Job Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE ("jobs"."job_type" ILIKE '%["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "permanent"]%')`
 when  select one of the option and this `Job Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE ("jobs"."job_type" ILIKE '%["0", "Full Timefull", "0", "Part Time", "0", "permanent"]%')` when i select multile option. As you can see thier are  these **"0"** in front of the actual label arrays which Sophie Déziel talk abot